# Composer - RuntimeException in RootPackageLoader after laminas-migration

Tags: composer-php, laminas

I have a strange issue with composer. Having installed as per website docs, and has been working perfectly for days. Updating a zf2 project to laminas. All seemed to be ok after a successful use of laminas-migrate. Updated the new laminas dependencies and was asked to inject Laminas\ComposerAutoloading into my modules.config.php - all ok. After that, i've been getting the following message when i run composer update:

> RootPackageLoader.php line 162:
>
> [RuntimeException]
> require.laminas/laminas-di  is invalid, it should have a vendor name, a forward slash, and a package name. The vendor and package name can be words separated by -, . or _. The complete name should match "^a-z0-9*/a-z0-9*$".

This even happens if i am in my project dir and run composer -V.
Strangely, if i cd / then run composer -V, i get the correct output (composer version without the RootPackageLoader exception).

I have deleted composer from /usr/local/bin and reinstalled, issue persists.

Comment: How does your `composer.json` look like?

Answer (score 0):

After a few evenings of going round in circles, i ended up deleting the whole project and starting afresh. This time, there were none of the above issues with laminas-migrate. The only thing i did differently was to run laminas-migrate on the project straight out of the repo, instead of trying to update all the packages to as-close-to-zf3 before migrating to laminas. Seemed to work fine.